# git ignore file still commits logs

Tags: git, ignore

I'm read all kinds of post on this and I just can't get it to work.

in my .ignore file I have

```
*/[Ll]ogs/*
```

Although I have tried about a dozen other variations, everything short of explicitly naming the file, I still am commiting these files

new file:    src/methodfitness.web/Logs/Trace.log.2012-03-15

I also had a similar problem helping a co worker exclude his web.config file but that's his problem now, I just don't want these bloody log files.

thanks,

R

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pattern `*/[Ll]ogs/*` will only match a logs folder that's one level depe. Yours is 3 levels deep. You also said ".ignore file", I hope you meant ".gitignore". Anyway, you can fix this in one of four ways:

1. Change the pattern to `src/*/[Ll]ogs/*`
2. Put the pattern `*/[Ll]ogs/*` into `src/.gitignore` instead of your root `.gitignore`
3. Change the pattern to just `[Ll]ogs/`. This will ignore any directory called "Logs" or "logs" in your entire tree. This may not be appropriate if you only want to ignore a directory of this name within your specific domain folders.
4. Put the pattern `*` into `src/methodfitness.web/Logs/.gitignore`. This will ignore all files in that folder. The benefit of this approach is git will still create the `Logs` folder when doing a checkout, which may or may not be something you want to happen. If you do this, make sure to explicitly add the `.gitignore` file, or it will end up ignoring itself.

---

On a related note, the trailing `*` is unnecessary. You can indicate directories with your ignore pattern and it will skip the entire directory. The only time when you want the trailing `*` is if you need to be able to un-ignore specific files (using the prefix `!` syntax, e.g. `!*/[Ll]ogs/goodfile.txt`)

Comment: yes .gitignore.  I was a bit frazzled when I wrote this.  Thank you for the explanation.  I will be using the [Ll]ogs/ one. Although I feel like I must have tried it there were so many permutations I probably missed that one.  Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

In order to ignore **all** log directories (and content too) at **any** deep inside your working copy you just have to read gitignore man mage and adopt example of ignoring foo dir from man-page.

For .gitignore in the root plain

```
logs/
```

pattern do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `[Ll]ogs/` as the ignore pattern.

Putting that pattern in the `.gitignore` file in the root of your directory structure should ignore all directories called either `Logs` or `logs` anywhere in the directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use so strange method?

To ignore all files under the `src/methodfitness.web/Logs/` folder, try to add to your .gitignore file appropriate line: `src/methodfitness.web/Logs/`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the double asterisks as described in the documentation of [git-scm (git version 2.16)](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

e.g.

```
**/[Ll]ogs
```

> Two consecutive asterisks ("**") in patterns matched against full pathname may have special meaning:
>
> - A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, "**/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, the
>     same as pattern "foo". "**/foo/bar" matches file or directory "bar"
>     anywhere that is directly under directory "foo".
> - A trailing "/**" matches everything inside. For example, "abc/**" matches all files inside directory "abc", relative to the location of the .gitignore file, with infinite depth.
> - A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches zero or more directories. For example, "a/**/b" matches "a/b", "a/x/b", "a/x/y/b" and so on.
>
> Other consecutive asterisks are considered invalid.